# Como fazer várias perguntas que envolvem a mesma tecnologia englobada?

Tags: debate, suporte

Fiz uma pergunta hoje no site e ela foi suspensa. 
É uma pergunta um tanto específica. 
Segue ela abaixo:

> ### https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38523/bluetooth-ou-wifidireto
>
> Minha aplicação é um guia para profissionais de iluminação que utilizam o equipamento x da minha empresa, com minha aplicação já rodando, pretendo fazer a comunicação com o tal equipamento x, para que quando eu operar o equipamento minha aplicação responder como deve, sem precisar a interação tablet <=> usuário. pretendo fazer algo assim. usuário=>equipamento=>tablet
>
> Em questão de preço bluetooth (módulo que entraria dentro do equipamento) mais ou menos mesmo preço do módulo wifi, dependendo de classe frequência e outros atributos de ambos.
>
> Agora que vem a grande pergunta qual utilizar?
>
> gostaria de saber em questão desempenho, qual se comporta melhor?
>
> em questão a implementação, qual é mais fácil?
>
> em questão a documentação, qual tem mais literaturas?
>
> em questão de estabilidade, qual que é mais estável?
>
> em questão do uso de bateria, qual que é mais econômico?
>
> lembrando que minha aplicação tem que ficar horas rodando sem interrupções e sem perder dados.
>
> > suspensa como amplo demais por bigown, brasofilo, Jorge B., RodrigoBorth, gmsantos 17 mins atrás
> >
> > Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.

A questão não é entender os 2, eu só gostaria de respostas curtas que me ajudasse a decidir, não longas literaturas,

**como fazer esse tipo de pergunta?**

Comment: Bom, você fez 6 perguntas dentro de uma só, e *cada uma delas* parece bem ampla... Isso não é "específico".

Comment: Podias perguntar "Quais são as principais vantagens e desvantagens de bluetooth e wifidireto?" e mesmo assim não sei...

Comment: Acho que a questão é focar em um problema concreto, apresentar seu know-how atual, sua pesquisa, e dividir o problema em várias perguntas se necessário (mas esperando o resultado de uma para partir para a seguinte).

Comment: Percebi na sua [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38556/ajuda-para-escolher-a-tecnologia) (também deletada; usuários com 2k+ podem ver posts deletados) que tem um problema de base... Seu problema é relacionado com programação? Parece que não... Na [help] tem as orientações e este Meta post mais detalhes: [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/201)

Comment: sim é referente a facilidade de programação, tbm a desempenho da aplicação, além disso, vantagens e desvantagens que tbm pesam do outro lado que tbm farei.

Comment: na verdade esse problema é tão amplo que envolve programação(grande parte) mas tbm de hardware, e como não é o foco só apontei dados relacionados a minha pesquisa para quem for responder levar em conta, mas conversando com colegas aqui na empresa chegamos a um consenso, ja. pode fechar tudo. @brasofilo

Comment: Eu não tenho poder para fechar nada, posso votar mas precisa de 5 pessoas para fechar alguma pergunta (ou 1 moderador). Como ainda não houve resposta a esta Meta pergunta, se você quiser deletar é livre para isso. Se quiser feedback sobre o problema, pode [edit] e mudar o foco... fica a seu critério.

Comment: vou deixar essa mais um tempo pq o foco dela é 
Como fazer várias perguntas que envolvem a mesma tecnologia englobada?
não a pergunta dada como exemplo. 
e criarei outra perguntando sobre contexto fora de foco

Answer (score 1):

Pode haver uma resposta que discuta seu caso tecnicamente, mas vou só citar e destacar as partes que acho relevantes na Central de Ajuda. Muitas delas são comuns em *toda* a rede Stack Exchange. E acho mais produtivo só continuar esta discussão ***depois*** que o AP (autor da pergunta) demonstrar que leu e compreendeu essas partes.

Parece que o tópico da pergunta encaixaria em:

> ### [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
>
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Os problemas que a pergunta tem aparecem em:

> ### [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
>
> Você deve fazer apenas **perguntas práticas**, que admitam respostas com base em **problemas reais que tiver**. [...]
>
> Suas perguntas devem ter um **escopo razoável**. Se você pode imaginar um *livro inteiro* que responda à sua pergunta, está perguntando demais.
>
> Se a sua motivação para fazer a pergunta for “eu gostaria de participar de **uma discussão sobre __**”, você não deve fazer uma pergunta aqui. [...]
>
> Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada e possivelmente removida, **evite fazer perguntas subjetivas** onde [...]
>
> Algumas perguntas subjetivas são permitidas, mas “subjetivo” não significa “qualquer coisa serve”. Todas as perguntas subjetivas devem ser **construtivas**.

O que se deve fazer para melhorar (minha interpretação entre parênteses):

> ### [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> - Procure e pesquise (demonstre sua pesquisa)
> - Limite-se ao contexto (confira os tópicos do site)
> - Seja específico (não peça para alguém escrever um livro)
> - Torne-a relevante para outros (tem que ser útil para toda internet, não só o AP)

Comment: Insisto que o AP leia a [help] devido à última pergunta que publicou (uma espécie de follow-up da questão original mostrada aqui na Meta)

Comment: não acho que isso resolve, por ser um problema especifico...

Comment: @Joannis, você leu ou não leu a [help]? Não dá pra ajudar se você não sabe o que é on-topic, o que é subjetivo, o que é muito amplo, etc.

Comment: 1- Central de ajuda > Perguntando
   A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas      aqui?"um problema específico de programação"

Central de ajuda > Perguntando
Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?
Você deve fazer apenas perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base em problemas reais que tiver. 

não vejo como ser amplo com um monte de perguntas do tipo booleana. 

gostaria de saber em questão desempenho, qual se comporta melhor? ou é um ou é o outro, n tem a ver com opnião, tem a ver com pesquisar práticas.

Comment: o mesmo vale para as outras, 
a razão da discussão seria como fazer a pergunta, 
acho que o problema de nossa discordância não é o fato de eu "não" saber o que é on-topic, o que é subjetivo, o que é muito amplo, etc.
mas o fato de termos interpretações diferentes em relação a mesma questão.

Comment: um problema específico de programação
relacionado a algumas causas e performasse de algumas bibliotecas. 

Você deve fazer apenas perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base em problemas reais que tiver

não vejo como esse problema não pode ser real, nem prático. 

em relação a conteúdo amplo ou responder um livro como você disse, 
também desconheço como alguém pode escrever um livro com algumas respostas do tipo esse ou aquele, e talvez algum exemplo ou link de documentação

Comment: Eu acho que nunca tinha visto uma pergunta mais patentemente ampla que essa no site. As respostas podem até ser curtas mas dependem das pessoas fazerem um trabalho de pesquisa extramente pesado para chegar no resultado. E pior, a maioria das pergunta**S** não são respondíveis. Ninguém sabe a resposta. No máximo, e olhe lá, pode ter uma opinião sem base, nada além disto. Mesmo que as perguntas fossem separadas, mesmo que todas elas fossem sobre programação ainda assim tenho dúvidas se alguma seria respondida corretamente e sem opinião,principalmente porque algumas respostas precisam de contexto

Comment: @Joannis, o melhor é você editar a pergunta se quiser expressar melhor e mais amplamente sua interpretação dos guias do site, e de porquê acha que sua pergunta é adequada. Eu não vou entrar nos detalhes de por que isto ou aquilo aqui na resposta ou comentários. É tudo amplo demais, esta Meta pergunta, a pergunta no site principal... se conseguir focar em um meta-problema de cada vez, acho mais produtivo. Enfim, acho que com o tempo vc pega o traquejo.